# How can I access SQLAlchemy table columns with a variable?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a table using SQLAlchemy with Python+Flask.

Let us call this table `Table`.

In table I have columns called `Col_1, Col_2,....Col_n`.

Is it possible for a given row to access the values in these columns in a for loop.

Here is what I tried:

```
row = Table.query.get(1) #returns the first row

for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(row.col_i)
```

But it throws an error that the attribute `row_i` does not exist.

How can I tell python that I want it to pull the value in `col_i` not search for the attribute `col_i` explicitly as this does not exist.

Comment: Perhaps `print(row.col_ + i)` Hope help you.

Comment: no this does not work.